# Newborn suction force on syringe

Tags: forces, fluid-dynamics, pressure

Just had a newborn. He requires assisted feeding through a syringe connected to a small catheter.

We place the small bendy catheter in his mouth, so he, simulating natural lactation, sucks the milk out of the syringe.

In the hospital, I was told that the bigger the syringe, the less force he would have to do to suck -on his own- the milk from the syringe.

Is this true?

[This is the connector attached to the syringe](https://www.vygon.es/content_prd-img/prd_disp_img_000817057.jpg)

Comment: The hospital staff no doubt have a lot of experience in this area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the piston in the syringe is unattended, then there are two forces acting on the piston.  One is the area times the difference in pressure between the atmosphere and the suction. The other is the friction between the piston and the walls of the syringe (perhaps with a rubber seal). Since the area increases with the square of the radius, and the friction probably with the first power of the radius, a larger piston should be easier to move by a pressure difference.